# powershell write xml with no escaping

Tags: xml, powershell, escaping

I have the following XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo>
  <bar key="baz" value='
{
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "c": "info"
    }
  }
}
' />
</foo>
```

I want to load this file in ps, do some work with it then save it back. At the moment, what I do is the following:

```
$xmlDocument = [System.Xml.XmlDocument]::new()
$xmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace = $true
$xmlDocument.Load('.\my.xml')

$settings = [System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings]@{
    Encoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new($true)
    Indent   = $true
}

$xmlWriter = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create('.\my.xml', $settings)
try {
    $xmlDocument.Save($xmlWriter)
}
finally {
    $xmlWriter.Dispose()
}
```

And I get the following output.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<foo>
    <bar key="baz" value="&#xD;&#xA;{&#xD;&#xA;  &quot;a&quot;: {&#xD;&#xA;    &quot;b&quot;: {&#xD;&#xA;      &quot;c&quot;: &quot;info&quot;&#xD;&#xA;    }&#xD;&#xA;  }&#xD;&#xA;}&#xD;&#xA;" />
</foo>
```

Is it possible to write this file without escaping the values?

Comment: Are you trying to write JSON into XML element attribute value? If so, [what for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)?

Comment: If you can modify the schema, I recommend storing the JSON as element text, so you can use a [CDATA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2784183/7571258) section to prevent any escaping: `<bar key="baz"><![CDATA[{ some json }]]></bar>`

Comment: @zett42 I can't really change it.

Comment: @vonPryz I totally get it. Some colleagues made some bad decision when writing the Web.config in an asp.net project and now I have to find a way for these changes...

Comment: Just an idea: Try to override `XmlWriter` methods that write attributes, e. g. `WriteAttributes`, `WriteAttributeString`

Comment: I solved it in an unorthodox way. I did what I had to do to the XML file, and when I would encounter a JSON value, I would keep it in an array, and replace that value with a GUID. I would save the XML doc with the changes made, and after that, I would open the file raw, regex match the GUID and replace it with the JSON value.